# What does trigger Chrome Address Autofill Popup using Angular Material

Tags: angular, forms, google-chrome, angular-material, autofill

In Chrome if we navigate to "Settings" and choose "Address and More"
[image]

then we are able to set up Addresses, that can be suggested by the browser on some forms.
[image]

I would like to understand, what exactly triggers the showing up of the Address Suggestion Pop-Up using Angular Material.

In my fist approach I tried following code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label [attr.aria-label]="'First Name'">First Name</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text" />
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label [attr.aria-label]="'Last Name'">Last Name</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text" />
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label [attr.aria-label]="'City'">City</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text" />
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label [attr.aria-label]="'Street'">Street</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text" />
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label [attr.aria-label]="'Postal Code'">Postal Code</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text" />
</mat-form-field>
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularmaterialautofill?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Note, that I'm NOT looking for the autocomplete, which looks like this:

[image]

The question is regarding this popup:

[image]

What exatly triggers this popup from the DOM? What can trigger it using Angular Material?

---EDIT---

In a Google Developer Post I found following:

"In the past, many developers would add autocomplete="off" to their form fields to prevent the browser from performing any kind of autocomplete functionality. While Chrome will still respect this tag for autocomplete data, it will not respect it for autofill data."

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill

So there must be something else, than `autocomplete` attribute, that triggers the Address Autofill.

For example this Form does trigger the Address Autofill if we click on `City`:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

And if we check out the `City` element in the DOM, its form has `autocomplete="off"` and the `City` element itself does not have `autocomplete` attribute.
[image]

Comment: Maybe: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete

Comment: @R.Richards that is `autocomplete` which controlls the first screenshot. That is what I'm not looking for. I'm looking for the info, what triggers the address autofill of the browser which is my second screenshot above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the 'name' attribute to your inputs. [See this link for usable values.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#values) The browser basically guesses at what values to provide for the autocomplete based on the 'name' attribute you add.

Comment: If the Address Suggestion Pops up with just the name, thats also fine. :)
I added some address specific fields, hoping that will trigger the required suggestion. But its is not the case. I tried adding the `name`, it does not help.

Comment: I think I did not interpret your answer well. You meant the `name` but not `autocomplete` with the `name` value? There is the `name` attribute for example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_name.asp.
I thought you mean `autocomplete="name"`, as there was a reference to `autocomplete`.
Using `<input matInput type="text" name="name" />` the autofill pops up!

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, I'll try to answer more clearly in the future. Glad you got it worked out! Consider accepting the answer if it helped ;)

Comment: Thank you, my friend!